# Feedback to proof about limit for $a(n)= \frac{n!}{n^{n}}$ and $b(n):=\frac{3^{n+2}- 2^{n}}{3^{n} + n}$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

> I have the following task: Determine whether the following defined sequences $a, b: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ or $a, b: \mathbb{N}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\} \cup \{\infty\}$ converge and, if necessary, determine the respective limit value.

$$a(n):= \frac{n!}{n^{n}}$$

[What I tried so far regarding the above task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgANc.jpg)

$$b(n):=\frac{3^{n+2}- 2^{n}}{3^{n} + n}$$

[What I tried so far regarding the above task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDxqy.jpg)

I would like to get a feedback regarding what I tried so far.
What I did is correct? If not, where is my error and How can I improve?
Explanations would be amazing.

Thank you!

Comment: For the first, that is correct however you have a typo... you rewrote the same expression on the right side of when you started sandwiching.  It should have read $0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$.  For the second, it seems fine if not a bit wordy.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please do not use pictures. Please learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, [here](http://asciimath.org) is an online converter.